# I just want to animate my character. nothing i do is working right

Tags: mesh, rigging

1. tried with one rigify, feet didnt move properly.
2. tried regenerating new rig from new armature and ran into all kinds of problems.
3. tried saving my model as fbx, uploaded into new project without textures.
4. anything i try to do with my model makes blender move slow as crap and i dont know where i went wrong to make my files so large.

My blend file is 3gb large. and it wont allow me to upload it. what should i do??

*EDIT*
So what was happening was i was attempting to use rigify to animate a model ive been working on. But the feet werent moving and i couldn't figure out how to weight paint the right way. But with the help of one of the suggested videos i stopped using rigify and weight painted the feet with the armature and now i think i have fixed my problem. i can now animate my 3d model and move on to trying to make a youtube intro with him.

Comment: try in a new blend file with rigging a free CC0 character. your blender file should only be around 5mb. thats why it's very slow

Comment: how do i get my file size smaller?? where did i go wrong?

Comment: i reduced my file size to about 176mb. is that good enough? im still getting an error when trying to upload it here.

Comment: You just tell things didn't work as you expected, but you don't actually explain any of your issues. How do you expect anyone to help without knowing what's going on? I suggest you to edit your post and explain exactly the first issue: tell us exactly what you expected, what is actually happening, and provide screenshots, gifs, whatever you can. Anything that can help us understand the situation and help you solve it.

Comment: i stopped using rigify and am weight painting properly now. theres so much to this program i didnt really know how to ask it. but im figuring it out slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best that you take a moment to learn the basics before you start deep diving into a time-saving add-on like Rigify. Follow along with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LIH_T3irRY) about how to rig a bouncy ball, then maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw) one about how to rig a more simple character from scratch, and work your way up the chain of difficulty, ultimately toward rigging a more complex character.

Only then, once you feel like you've got a handle on things, you can start using addons like Rigify to speed up your workflow. If you jump  straight into an advanced workflow and use addons that skip over fundamental concepts then the moment you encounter the slightest error you'll have no idea of how to debug it and work around it.

You don't want to make using cool tools like Rigify as crutch to supplement weak areas in your own ability. Take a moment to build the muscle memory around fundamental concepts with simple exercises. Only start using Rigify when the primary emotion you're feeling during character rigging is boredom, rather than frustration or confusion.

Comment: i think my issue is moreso that i cant find the right tutorials for things when they go wrong. i may think im following a tutorial to a T. but blender has a way of programming certain muscle memories that most people in tuts dont explain very well. even when im watching every button they press i still end up confused. and unfortunately i learn best under high stress, confusion and frustration. if i dont make errors ill never know how to fix them right?

Comment: the only reason i knew to use rigify was from watching a tutorial lol. they didnt mention that it wasnt a beginner tool

Comment: It depends what you call "beginner". If you think a beginner knows the ground level of rigging and skinning, then Rigify is absolutely a beginner tool. If you think that a beginner tool should allow to fully rig a character without requiring the user any form of knowledge, then I'm afraid most tools are not "beginner tools" by far. Even Mixamo - which is designed to require as little experience as possible - still requires knowing a little, and when it goes wrong: you just can't make things work without base knowledge. It's not for nothing that it's an actual job to make rigs.

Comment: In the end, Blender isn't a competition, and we aren't all using it to show how "expert" we are at 3D software. It's a tool and a means to create art that we like. In every craft: painting, guitar, woodworking, sculpting, etc, you always start out by keeping the tools simple, taking it slow and working your way up to more advanced concepts and workflows. Don't worry about feeling frustrated, there isn't a person on this site that hasn't experienced the same feelings.

Comment: I would also spend a few minutes each day reading the Blender [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/). You can skip around, read whatever sections pique your interest, but that will help to start to lay a more solid foundation for "how Blender works" so you aren't just skipping from Youtuber to YouTuber telling you hotkeys for 6 months straight. It's less about hotkeys and more about concepts in the end.

Comment: Your recommended videos helped me solve it somehow. i appreciate everyones help and feedback! Dope Community. Next time ill be a bit more specific with my question

Comment: You got it dawg, keep it up!

Answer (score 2):

Try nice and simple and start with a free character online.

To get the absolute basics of rigging down, you can do a really simple example like this one here:

- Put your character into the scene
- put an armature over the character. You dont even have to align the bones very well to just get it working.
- click the character, then click the armature, then click *Ctrl + P* and click with *automatic weights*
- click on the armature and go into pose mode. Then move around bones. The rig should now be working

[image]

After you have successfully done this, I recommend trying the official blender tutorial series on rigging. It is well made and will help you understand the vast amount of errors you are encountering. You can find it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2pTkW-1JkE

Comment: my armature was working. its the rigify that wasnt. can i animate the armature also???